# Do any poskim permit one to recite Parshas Hamon on Tisha b’Av?

Tags: halacha, sources-mekorot, torah-study, tisha-bav

Do any poskim permit one who says parshas hamon daily the rest of the year to recite parshas hamon on tisha b’av as well?  And if so, which poskim?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The פסקי תשובות סימו תקנ"ד אות ד brings a minhag that relies on the ט"ז ס"ק ג which the פ"ת understands to hold that according to the רמ"א, anything that is part of the regular daily סדר השיעורים of a person is allowed to be said on תשעה באב.

The פסקי תשובות then goes on to mention Parshas Hamon as an example of what would fall under this היתר.

In his words:

> ומצינו מנהג כמה קהלות כדברי הט"ז (בדברי הרמ"א) ולא שינו את סדר השיעורים שהם לחם חוקם בכל יום ויום במשך ימות השנה כגון פרשת התשובה והמן וכו’ ועשו זאת לאחר חצות היום לעת מנחה, אמנם כאמור בשעה"צ (סקי"א) שהכרעת הפוסקים כהמג"א שיש להשלימם למחרת ולא לאומרם בט"ב

Comment: Rav Yitzchak Berkowitz (Rosh Yeshiva of Aish HaTorah and Rosh Kollel in Yerushalayim) put out a page of halachos for Tisha b"Av for his kollel and he said the same thing without quoting a source.